# Handling Like and Unlike of an entity in ASP.NET MVC using AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a razor view where the model is an IEnumerable of Product so I am simply listing all of the products in the view using a foreach loop on the Model. Along with each product you can see below that I am showing the count of how many ThumbsUps it has. The final thing I am trying to accomplish is when they click on the link 'Give Thumbs Up' I would like to add a ProductThumbsUp record to the database for the current logged in user. If the user already has given a thumbs up and clicks it again I would like to remove their ProductThumbsUp from the product.

I am using EntityFramework 7 and MVC6. I have two tables: Product and ProductThumbsUp.

I would like to know how I should go about adding a ProductThumbsUp record for the current logged in user when they click the link using MVC. I am assuming something like this should definitely be an AJAX post. But would I simply just want to send the ProductId to the AJAX post? Then in my controller create a new ProductThumbsUp and set the ProductId of it. Then send both the newly created ProductThumbsUp object and the current logged in user down to my repository layer for saving.

I am wondering if there are better ways to do this since each post in my model already has a list of ThumbsUps attached to it. Is there a better way I can be doing this?

**Here is how my razor view is setup:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>
@foreach (var product in Model)
{
    <h2>@product.Name</h2>
    <div>@product.Description</div>
    <a href="#" class="lnkViewLikes"># of Thumbs Ups Given:<span class="badge">@product.ThumbsUps.Count()</span></a>

    <a href="#" class="lnkThumbsUp">Give Thumbs Up</a>
}
```

**Here is what my Product model looks like:**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }

public ICollection<ProductThumbsUp> ThumbsUps { get; set; }
```

Comment: What your suggesting sounds the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it efficient,

I would recommend getting all the products and instead of getting all the rows of thumbsUps for each product from DB, just get the like count for each product.

As you dont need each row of thumbsUp but just the count to display. Imagine the scenario for scale if you have a million likes on a product, suddenly you are pulling a million rows from the DB to your server - just to show a count.

Also i would make a second call to the database to get all the thumbsUps the current user has given (a list of product Ids he has liked). That will allow you to display to the user if they have liked it or now.

To add the acutal thumbs up to the product - you can send an ajax call which tells which productId he liked and mvc action can insert a thumbsUp row to the database.

Comment: Great response, it got me thinking. When the user actually give a thumbs up would it be an AJAX POST to the controller? Also, as far as showing the user which products he has already given a thumbs up to I like the idea of just making a second database call to get all of that user's likes but wouldn't it be easier to have a ViewModel with the following: Id, Name, Description, ICollection<ThumbsUp> ThumbsUps, bool: UserLikes and then in the GET method of the controller after retrieving all of the Products and their Likes from the db do a query and set the UserLikes property then pass to view?

Comment: Can you give me an idea of what my ViewModel should look like for my Index.cshtml where I am listing all of the products? In my controller's GET Index method I am assuming I need to do more than just get all of the Products from the db. Lets say I run a second query to get all of the ProductIds that the current logged in user has liked. Should this also be a ViewModel property?

Comment: Many ways to skin this cat. One way - Index ViewModel could have an IEnumerable of ProductViewModel. Which has Id, Name, Description, Count to display the product. Also another bool LikedByCurrentUser. which is true / false based on whether current user has liked it or not.

Comment: Perfect I was thinking of something just like that! So then I would set LikedByCurrentUser with a linq query after retrieving all of the products I want to list and all of the products that user liked, I would do a query where the ids match and set those ones to LikedByCurrentUser. I know this it a bit of a general/broad question, but I really appreciate you getting my brain thinking properly. Looks like I am on a good path!

Comment: Moxplod one final question because it caused a bit of confusion on my end. When you said just get the count and not everything else to be more efficient did you mean only set the count of the ViewModel or did you mean from the database do not do an Includes and only get the Count directly from sql

Comment: I meant you should not get all the rows of ThumbsUps table(ICollection in your Product table) from the database itself. Just the count of ThumbsUps per Product as that is all you need.

Comment: Hmm using entity framework isn't something like this a pain? That means I would have to add a property called ThumbsUpCount to my Product model itself... then it would get added as a column to the database. wouldnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do it is Create Two **anchor** tags

Give Thumbs Up
   Remove Thumbs Up

And toggle it using javascript or jquery.
Similarly call method using jquery ajax to add and remove the count(can use the same method using a flag)
Using the same method you can return the new Count and bind it

Comment: This is pretty much how I will be doing things. Thank you for confirming it for me. I will be using 2 links like you said and one function that handles everything in an ajax post then on success update the count.